# apt-get install does not work

Tags: apt

I want to install snmp on my computer. Evey time I do `apt-get install snmp snmpd mbrowse` it displays this message:

```
reading packages list...Fait
building dependency tree
reading state informations... fait
package snmp is not available but it is refered to bu another package. this may mean that the package is missing , has been obsoleted or is only available from another source
however the following package replace it:
libsnmp15
```

I don't understand the problem. I mean apt-get is supposed to be a first step to configure snmp. If the downloading is such a mess, how the configuration would be?

Comment: "Reading packages list... Fail". Run `sudo apt-get update` to download the package lists.

Comment: Does it say `fail`, or is it `fait` (as you wrote)?

Comment: The answer is in the output:

package snmp is not available but it is refered to bu another package. this may mean that the package is missing , has been obsoleted or is only available from another source
however the following package replace it:
libsnmp15

Comment: how can solve this probrem do you have any idea

Comment: For reference' sake: *Fait* is French for *done*.

Comment: yes i know, could you help me please

Answer (score 1):

Run `apt-get update` before running `apt-get install`.

Comment: i did this and it solves nothing

Comment: when i run apt-get update, it says that some files were not updated

Comment: Please be more explicit. What exactly is the error message?